# Why does localhost and 127.0.0.1 resolve to different locations on Mac OSC 10.8?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I set up a local server without MAMP, for various reasons. I used this tutorial: [Install and configure Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin on OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion)

I'm just wondering why the local IP and localhost resolve to two different locations. Right now the IP resolves to a Virtual Host I set up and the localhost resolves to the `DocumentRoot` established by `httpd.conf`

Comment: I think you are using the word "resolve" in a non-standard way. Are you talking about what you get from a web server?

Comment: I mean that when I type localhost an index file in the `DocumentRoot` draws. When I type 127.0.0.1 another index page draws, from the `DocumentRoot` of my Virtual Host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two (or more) virtual hosts set up. One is set to listen on localhost, the other is set to listen on 127.0.0.1.

Or more likely, one is set to listen on either 127.0.0.1 or localhost, and the other is set to listen on any connection and is picking up whichever the first is not.

Take a look at your virtual hosts - note that virtual hosts can be created in multiple locations on OSX - either under the system as a whole or per-user. You probably want to either remove the virtual host, or set it to listen under both addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at /private/etc/hosts and make sure that **127.0.0.1** is associated with **localhost**, like so...

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```